# Need to add a blank page in my crystal reports between pages of certain type

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

So basically, I'm generating a crystal report pdf in which the source is from a datatable having certain values. There is a certain column Gross_Amount in the datatable where the value can be either > 0 or = 0. All are generating within a single PDF.

All rows > 0 are generated first followed by the ones with 0. I need a blank page between the two. i.e First all with > 0 are generated followed by a blank page , then the ones with = 0. All are generating within a single PDF.

Thanks.

Comment: Is each page comprised of one and only one `details` section?  Does your report have any groups?  Do page breaks occur along group boundaries?

Comment: Yes it consist of only 1 Details section and it does not contain any groups or page breaks.

Comment: Do you need an actual blank page between the two or is it OK to have the zero-values start on a new page?

Comment: yup a blank page is what I'm looking for. Im able to generate the PDF first with values > 0 then with value = 0 but cant get a blank page between them. Basically the blank page is the identifier separating the two.

Comment: could you please post the layout of your report?

Comment: @cojimarmiami im not sure what you meant, do u need a sample generated or do you need the crystal report layout i.e .rpt file layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula:

```
//{@Is Zero?}
If {table.Gross_Amount}=0 Then True Else False
```

Insert a group on this formula (use ASC ordering).  It will create `GH1` and `GF1` sections.

Insert a second GH section (it will be named 'GH1b'); move this section outside/above current 'GH1a'; it will become the new GH1a

Add this text to the GH1a's `New Page Before` conditional formula:

```
{@Is Zero?}
```

Add this text to the GH1a's `New Page After` conditional formula:

```
{@Is Zero?}
```

This will create a blank GH section between the two non-blank sections, but will also include the PH/PF sections.  Still trying to find a way to suppress these.